# Notices on the front-end

Tags: notices

I am reposting. As my last questions wasn't famous.

My users are submitting custom post types (projects) from the frontend. How do I display notices (such as the one displayed on admin board) to the front end for when the user performs an action, example edit a post.

I know there are hooks for update/submit (post_updated_messages...) but those do not display anything on the frontend.

I tried putting the following but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter('post_updated','alert_user');

function alert_user()
{
add_action('display_message','prepare_text');
}

function prepare_text(){
return 'You did it!';
}
```

in my theme I have

```
do_action('display_message');
```

It doesn't work as prepare_text is never hooked to display_message!

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Next time, **improve** the existing question. Do not just ask the same question again.

Comment: I did. But my question didn't get any interactions. Now, you can see. I've got an answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could filter `the_content`:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'wpse105892_add_message', 10 );
function wpse105892_add_message() {
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse105892_display_message' );
}

function wpse105892_display_message( $content ) {
    // remove the action once it's run
    remove_action( 'post_updated', 'wpse105892_add_message', 11 );

    $content = "<div class='your-message'>You did it!</div>\n\n" . $content;
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know! Thanks! Just curious, is there a reason why it would work on a core hook 'the_content' and not on my own hook.

Comment: If you've added a hook of your own that displays in the front end, then sure, you can hook it to that instead.  I didn't see anything in your question about creating your own hook (is it `display_message`?).

Comment: Yes. It is display_message!

Comment: Can you update your question to show how/where your `display_message` hook is created, please?

Comment: Maybe this is my mistake. I use only add_action in the first function and then do_action (as seen above). Am I supposed to do anything else?

Comment: `post_updated` is an action hook, not a filter.  So you'd want to `add_action( 'post_updated', 'alert_user' );`.

Comment: That still works even with add_filter. The question is with regards to these 2 lines: add_action('display_message','prepare_text'); and do_action('display_message');  Is it enough to create a hook?

Comment: Tried your suggestion solution above. But no success.

Comment: More information on what happened: The prepare_Text doesn't even get called. Here is the code:add_action('post_updated','alert_user',10);

function alert_user()
{
    add_filter('the_content','prepare_text');
}

function prepare_text($content){
    dump('aaaa');
    remove_action( 'post_updated', 'alert_user', 11 );
    $string = '<div class="alert alert-success">Hola<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>';
    return $string.$content;
}

Comment: This question has blocked me for over a month now. Any help is very much appreciated. All I want to do is be able to display notices to the user (front-end) based on certain actions. Update-post, Unauthorized action...

Comment: I have checked. The hook is actually added, the problem is with the redirection. The forms are created using gravity form. Once the form is submitted there is a redirect. And because of this redirect, the notice gets lost in the redirect. Any directions on how to solve this.

Comment: Hmmm. I know Gravity Forms has [a bunch of actions and filters](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs) you can tap in to.  Maybe one of these is what you need.